# SQL Single Row query advice

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Can i please get some help with my SQL report query, i am 90% there just need the last step (still learning SQL so be kind :) ).

We currently have 2 different databases:
- [DATABASE1] stores all our assets
- [DATABASE2] stores all assets that we are still paying off
- - This database stores every payment made against the asset to the bank, the date the payment was made, the amount etc.
- - The last row against the asset will be the last payment, and the date on this would be the expected lease end date.

I would like a report that will have a single line per asset shows all columns.
My current report shows all the required information, however it shows ALL the rows per asset instead of a single encapsulated row, e.g:

```
ASSET NO | FINANCIER | AGEEMENT NUMBER | PAYMENT NUMBER | LEASE COMMENCE DATE | LEASE FINAL DATE | MONTHLY PAYMENTS
asset1 | bank 1 | 1111 | 1 | 01/01/2017 | NULL | NULL
asset1 | bank 1 | 1111 | 2 | NULL | NULL | 2000
asset1 | bank 1 | 1111 | 3 | NULL | NULL | NULL
..
asset1 | bank 1 | 1111 | 20 | NULL | 01/01/2020 | NULL
asset2 | bank 5 | 1536 | 1 | 05/08/2016 | NULL | NULL
..
```

Instead of:

```
ASSET NO | FINANCIER | AGEEMENT NUMBER | PAYMENT NUMBER | LEASE COMMENCE DATE | LEASE FINAL DATE | MONTHLY PAYMENTS
    asset1 | bank 1 | 1111 | 20 | 01/01/2017 | 01/01/2020 | 2000
    asset2 | bank 5 | 1536 | 15 | 05/08/2016 | 12/05/2019 | 5500
    ..
```

Below is my query:

```
Declare @MaxPays TABLE (
    ITEMNO VARCHAR(MAX),
    PAYNO VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @MaxPays
SELECT
    a.ITEMNO,
    a.PAYNO
FROM 
    [DATABASE1] a
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT ITEMNO, MAX(PAYNO) as PAYNO FROM [DATABASE1] GROUP BY ITEMNO) AS b ON
    a.ITEMNO = b.ITEMNO AND a.PAYNO = b.PAYNO

SELECT
    a.ITEMNO as 'Asset #',
    a.FINANCE as 'Financier',
    a.AGREENO as 'Agreement number',
    a.PAYNO as 'Payment Number',
        CASE WHEN a.PAYNO = 1 THEN a.PAYDATE ELSE NULL END as 'Lease Commencing Date',
        CASE WHEN a.PAYNO = (SELECT PAYNO FROM @MaxPays WHERE ITEMNO = a.ITEMNO) THEN a.PAYDATE ELSE NULL END as 'Lease Finalising Date',
        CASE WHEN a.PAYNO = 2 THEN a.PAYAMOUNT ELSE NULL END as 'Monthly Payments'
FROM 
    [DATABASE1] a
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT ITEMNO from [DATABASE2]) AS b ON
    a.ITEMNO = b.ITEMNO
ORDER BY a.ITEMNO
```

**EDIT:** The monthly payment links to the 2nd instance because sometimes the 1st payment includes down payments, and isnt a clear indicator of the recurring monthly payments

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: First, you should tag the `RDMS` instead of just `sql`.  Back to your question, you need to use `GROUP BY`, however, I can't provide the answer as I don't understand you logic;  Lease Commencing Date seems is `min`, Lease Finalising Date seems `max`, but the Monthly Payments...

Comment: Thanks for the comments, sorry i should have clarified. The monthly payment links to the 2nd instance because sometimes the 1st payment includes down payments, and isnt a clear indicator of the recurring monthly payments. Thanks

Comment: Maybe I have confuse you, `RDMS` not the `RDMS` tag I mean, but something like `sql-server`, `oracle`, `mysql`.  And do you mean Monthly Payments should be the value of last record which same as Max(Lease Finalising Date)?

Comment: Monthly payment never changes after the 2nd instance, it is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a minor modification in your query -

```
SELECT
a.ITEMNO as 'Asset #',
a.FINANCE as 'Financier',
a.AGREENO as 'Agreement number',
a.PAYNO as 'Payment Number',
MAX(CASE WHEN a.PAYNO = 1 THEN a.PAYDATE ELSE NULL END) as 'Lease Commencing Date',
MAX(CASE WHEN a.PAYNO = (SELECT PAYNO FROM @MaxPays WHERE ITEMNO = a.ITEMNO) THEN a.PAYDATE ELSE NULL END) as 'Lease Finalising Date',
MAX(CASE WHEN a.PAYNO = 2 THEN a.PAYAMOUNT ELSE NULL END) as 'Monthly Payments'
FROM 
[DATABASE1] a
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT ITEMNO from [DATABASE2]) AS b ON
a.ITEMNO = b.ITEMNO
GROUP BY a.ITEMNO,
         a.FINANCE,
         a.AGREENO,
         a.PAYNO,
ORDER BY a.ITEMNO
```

Comment: It appears this throws an error: 'Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery'